# way to find lowest unique bidder

Tags: mysql

hey i want to find lowest unique bid depend on product id because every product have diff. id so when product is hited it got product id and then depend on product id it will find lowest unique bid and then display username of that lowest unique bidder.

Here is a picture of some sample data inside that table:

[image]

plz provide me full code for that.I will be very thankfull for u all guys.

```
$productid=$_session['productid'];

  select bidamount, userName,productid
  from bid
  where
     productid = '$productid'
     and bidamount = (
             select min(lowest_bid.bidamount)
             from bid lowest_bid
             where
               lowest_bid.productid = '$productid'
             group by lowest_bid.bidamount
             having count(distinct lowest_bid.userName) = 1
             order by closing_date
             limit 1
             )
```

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: what is that query that you posted? an attempt to solve your problem? did it fail? where?

Comment: "*plz provide me full code*" is not what SO is for.

Comment: No this is not a free coding service, its for help with a specific issue. Comments like `plz provide me full code` are not looked on kindly.

Answer (score 0):

If i am reading your question correctly, you can perform the request quite simply by using the SQL statement:

```
select productid, min(bidamount) from bid where productid='$productid' group by productid
```

you could also skip using the group clause completely and use

```
select productid, bidamount, username from bid where( select min(bidamount) from bid where productid='$productid')=bidamount
```